# How can i handle really long-term running tasks?

Tags: architecture, message-queue, task, service-workers

Im not dealing with a x minute task that can use an message queue and some workers to be done. Lets say that i have an cctv camera that capture 24/7, but can be stopped or started again via Web API for example. In this example i can't just use normal task queue (like [Bull](https://optimalbits.github.io/bull/) in js or [Celery](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html) in python) as each worker will stuck with only 1 infinite task forever.

So how can i start x "tasks" of processing different cctv cams that will be running in the worst case all the time until i stop?

Comment: Possibly a task is the wrong abstraction here. How about an autoscaling worker pool with a Least Connection load balancer? Alternatively, is there a reason that the camera stream needs to be processed as a continuous stream vs splitting it up into an infinite stream of finite tasks processing a defined window.

Comment: what exactly is the problem with the naïve solution. ie listen to a queue for starts and stops, spin up worker processes as required?

Comment: Marking current/desired state in database and waiting for an event to run a handler may work better than hanging a thread on the task.

Comment: I have trouble to understand your scenario. Are you talking about a movie camera which produces a steady stream of 25 or more images per second which are saved into a single file after some time, or a photo camera which produces single images and image files, maybe also in certain time intervals. And what are your expectations about the consumers? Shall they process movie files some hours later? Or continuosly during the moves or single photos are produced? It would be nice if you could elaborate on the whole scenario and tell us more details.

Comment: @user1937198 i guess splitting it up has scalling advantages but for my scenario it is not possible as need to be processed as a continuous stream, im dealing with computer vision functionalities such as object tracking that needs frames in chronological order or simply to record and save an video. Im also thinking about be possible to change some configuration parameters eg. change the size of the area of interest, would i need to stop the current worker and start in another with these changes?

Comment: @DocBrown it is a security cam in live, in a pratical example lets say that i will have an API that will "trigger" the "task" of beguin processin xyz functionalities (like object tracking and/or movement) in cam01. that way the task will connect to the cam and start processing eg. notifying when object stay in the scene for 5 seconds. With the API i need to stop that process as well as change the parameter for notify if object stay for 20 seconds.

Comment: @Vrrl What happens in your system when a cameras network connection is disconnected for maintenance? How do you handle that scenario. Could you separate the process of generating object tracking events into a separate process that works over window of frames, and a process that works with those events and a stream of frames to generate a stored video?

Comment: @user1937198 i have full control when connection is lost, so i can send an alert or retry connection. idk if i understand you correctly, but i guess it is possible. Are you talking about diferent functtionalities (obj track, record) in diferents system processes/servers?

Comment: @Vrrl What happens if the cable breaks or there is a power failure or the camera breaks? Since you talk about multiple cameras I assume a vaguely distributed system, but even if not there is the potential for an unexpected loss of power/power surge event taking out the camera unexpectedly. At the most extreme, what happens in the event of a lightning strike to the cabling? You are never in full control of when the connection is lost.

Comment: @Vrrl my point was by building in the capability to handle breaks in underlying connection transmitting frames, you should be able to turn this into a task processing problem by artificially inducing breaks at fixed intervals, and transferring the state that way. Look at distributed streaming engines like spark streaming or apache flink checkpointing for examples of this.

Answer (score 1):

I may not fully understand your question so I will paraphrase what I think you are asking: You defining the scope of a CCTV camera 'task' to be the time from when it is started/enable until the time it is shutdown/disabled.  The challenge is that the time that a given camera is 'up' could be days, weeks, or longer.  So this 'task' would remain active during that time in the scheduler.

If that is a correct understanding of the question, I think you will want to rethink the scope of the 'task' for the scheduler.  In my experience, scheduling tools do not handle really long tasks well and often they have hard limits on how long a task can run before they are considered to be in an error state.  Please clarify if this is not a correct understanding of your quandary.

From a scheduler's perspective, I think you want at least two types of tasks:

- starting the camera
- stopping the camera

And you may want to have another task which is verifying that the camera is working while it is in the 'started' state.  This could be addressed in other ways as well.  Each of these tasks are discrete and manageable in a scheduling tool.

Comment: you understand my question correctly, im also think that a task queue [is not the best option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31692107/celery-and-long-running-tasks).
My problem is with scaling, as i need to support just 1 or 100 cctvs and idk if there's a pattern or common term for this type of needs. For now im thinking about making an Manager that can handle x cctvs in one VM and scale the Managers as it need, them i can control Start, Stop and update state with an self made logic.

Comment: @Vrrl my first thought is that if this Celery tool isn't doing what you need it to do, then just don't use it and write your own code. Unless you're required to use it. You basically have these threads that process camera data; one computer can handle a certain number of camera processing threads; if you want to have more than that, you buy a faster computer, or you make a system that works on more than one computer at a time.

Comment: @user253751 i guess that is my answer. I was just afraid to make my own code when someone already develop some type of lib. I still don't know how these type of software/logic/pattern is called, so i will just assume that is a "long-term task queue/manager".

Comment: @Vrrl I'm sure someone did develop it but the one you are using is not that. Don't be afraid to write code.

Comment: @user253751 I don't see any reason you couldn't do it the way I have described here.  Schedulers are designed for work with a clearly defined start and end.  Things like parsing a file and saving the data from it to a DB.  They aren't really designed for things that run for indefinite amounts of time.  Such systems do exist e.g.: container runtimes that ensure N instances are always running.  Starting and stopping a camera can fit into a job scheduler and so can a status check.  The trick is linking these three types of tasks together properly.

Answer (score -1):

Very partial answer: at some point you need to take into account that your computer can crash, and you need to recover from that as well as you can.

Before that, you need to take into account that you may run out of battery, and make sure that everything goes well when running out of powe and the computer is plugged in later.

Answer (score -1):

> how can i start x "tasks" of processing different cams that will be running in the worst case all the time until i stop

Seems like you are describing a distributed producer/consumer problem that can be taken care of using three actors `Producer` , `TaskManager` and `TaskWorker`

I would consider each camera as a `Producer` that is "producing" a stream of events (or data points if you will) that need to be processed.
Events from a particular "producer" can be assigned a `producer_id` and a `timestamp` to maintain separation per producer

On the consumption end:

I would consider a `TaskManager` that "manages" the stream from a producer. It would have a single responsibility of making sure that all events are processed. If you consider processing an event as a `Task` then `TaskManager` **ensures** all tasks created by a producers are handled. It would perform audit / writing down metadata about process in case the processing needs to be replayed/retried in case of failures.

A `TaskWorker` process would be actor that actually does the processing of the `Task`. As long as it has all the information available to "process" the task available from the `TaskManager`, it would not care about the big picture of the system.

A `TaskManager` would be a level that I would scale up/down depending pressure on the system

Comment: it seems a reasonable answer but i'm a bit confused, can you draw a simple flow of this?

Comment: can someone explain what could be improved in my answer and clarify the downvote ?